# showmount -e fails from one node

Tags: nfs, rpc

When I run:

```
showmount -e <IP>
rpc mount export: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection reset by peer

mount <IP>:/path /mnt
mount.nfs: Connection reset by peer
```

But

```
mount -t nfs -c vers=3 <IP>:/path /mnt
```

works

The client and server (freenas 9.3) are on the same subnet. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure packets aren't being blocked by a firewall. I would recommend issuing `iptables -L -v` before and after you issue the `showmount` command. If you see the counters on the left increase for a DROP rule, chances are you need to insert a rule to allow for NFS clients to connect. Here's some information from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-fedora-rhel-iptables-open-nfs-server-ports/:

> The portmapper assigns each NFS service to a port dynamically at
> service startup time. How do I allow legitimate NFS clients to access
> the NFS server using RHEL / Fedora / CentOS Linux 5.x iptables
> firewall?
>
> You need to open the following ports: a] TCP/UDP 111 - RPC 4.0
> portmapper
>
> b] TCP/UDP 2049 - NFSD (nfs server)
>
> c] Portmap static ports - Various TCP/UDP ports defined in
> /etc/sysconfig/nfs file. Configure NFS Services to Use Fixed Ports
>
> However, NFS and portmap are pretty complex protocols. Firewalling
> should be done at each host and at the border firewalls to protect the
> NFS daemons from remote access, since NFS servers should never be
> accessible from outside the organization. However, by default, the
> portmapper assigns each NFS service to a port dynamically at service
> startup time.
>
> Dynamic ports cannot be protected by port filtering firewalls such as
> iptables. First, you need to configure NFS services to use fixed
> ports. Open /etc/sysconfig/nfs, enter:
>
> ```
> # vi /etc/sysconfig/nfs
> ```
>
> Modify config directive as follows to set TCP/UDP unused ports:
>
> ```
> # TCP port rpc.lockd should listen on. LOCKD_TCPPORT=lockd-port-number
> # UDP port rpc.lockd should listen on. LOCKD_UDPPORT=lockd-port-number 
> # Port rpc.mountd should listen on. MOUNTD_PORT=mountd-port-number
> # Port rquotad should listen on. RQUOTAD_PORT=rquotad-port-number
> # Port rpc.statd should listen on. STATD_PORT=statd-port-number
> # Outgoing port statd should used. The default is port is random STATD_OUTGOING_PORT=statd-outgoing-port-numbe
> ```
>
> Here is sample listing from one of my production NFS server:
>
> ```
> LOCKD_TCPPORT=32803 LOCKD_UDPPORT=32769 MOUNTD_PORT=892
> RQUOTAD_PORT=875 STATD_PORT=662 STATD_OUTGOING_PORT=2020
> ```
>
> Save and close the files. Restart NFS and portmap services:
>
> ```
> # service portmap restart
> # service nfs restart
> # service rpcsvcgssd restart Update /etc/sysconfig/iptables files
> ```
>
> Open /etc/sysconfig/iptables, enter:
>
> ```
> # vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
> ```
>
> Add the following lines, ensuring that they appear before the final
> LOG and DROP lines for the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT chain:
>
> ```
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24  -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 32803 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24  -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 32769 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24  -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 892 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24  -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 892 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24  -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 875 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24  -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 875 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24  -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 662 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 662 -j ACCEP
> ```
>
> Save and close the file. Replace 192.168.1.0/24 with your actual LAN
> subnet /mask combo. You need to use static port values defined by
> /etc/sysconfig/nfs config file. Restart iptables service:
>
> ```
> # service iptables restart
> ```